# Alternative to guaranteed copy elision

Tags: c++, icc, c++17

C++17 introduces [guaranteed copy elision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision), but the feature is presently not implemented for [some compilers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support) (in particular Intel C++ 17 and 18).

I currently have a SIMD program compiled with Intel C++ 17 where copy/move elision is not optimized away, resulting in SIMD serialization for an assignement that is useless in the first place (further resulting in non-negligible performance loss).

My program would look like so:

```
class X { ... };

struct S {
   // default ctor, default copy/move ctor/assignement
   // and recursivly so for all data members
   // no virtual member functions
   ...
   constexpr
   S(const X& x) : ... {}

   constexpr auto
   update(const X& x) {
       ...
   }
};

constexpr auto
make_S(const X& x) { // note : except for being templated, make_S is not simplified from my real implementation. 
                     // I only want to use it for overloading, allowing the caller to not specify the actual type of S
  return S(x); // Yes, that simple :'(
}

constexpr auto
init_S(S& s, const X& x) { 
  s.update(x);
}

int main() {
  X x;

  S s(x); // copy elision success
  // vs
  auto s = make_S(x); // icc does not elide the move
  // vs
  S s;
  init_S(s,x); // no copy

  return 0;
}
```

As I understand, C++17 would require copy elision, and as a matter of fact, with deleted move/copy ctors, gcc 7.2 with -std=c++17 accepts the code. But icc 17, even with -std=c++17 does not elide a move on complex cases.

Is there a way to ensure copy elision optimization on Intel C++ ? From what I can tell, optimization is done most of the time, but some complex cases fail without obvious reasons. What could be the reason of failed copy elision ?

Note: all functions are `inline`, and inlined by the compiler.

*Side question*: how good was copy elision optimizations during the C++14 era, before it became mandatory? I seem to recall that clang similarly did not optimized away everything it could have.

Comment: Can you post code with not optimized copy-elision you encounter ?

Comment: @Jarod42 It's complicated. I'd like to first try to gather answers from people that experienced with icc first, because it seems to me that the compiler is not so smart about return by value. The problem with posting the code here means extracting it, but it can't be too simple because then the compiler do elide the copy. It is a lot of work.

Comment: @Jarod42 If the question is : does your code really satisfy the copy elision preconditions of the standard, the answer is: almost certainly :)

Comment: It is indeed the underlying question, and without code, it is just speculation.

Comment: You could completely avoid the return statement and "return" the output using a reference argument.

Comment: @pschill I know and that's what make me mad: why would it be so complicated for a compiler to do exactly what it would do if I just pass by non-const reference :(

Comment: @Jarod42 I edited the question with pseudo-code that reflects the problem. As I understand, requirements for copy/move garanteed elision are very weak and the ones you would expect.

Comment: @NicolBolas Good catch. I corrected the code. There is no call to ctor in init_S

Comment: I can't see a single [move constructor call](https://godbolt.org/g/2AGTWq) on your snippet in any of the ICC versions supported by godbolt.

Comment: @T.C. Yes because this code is simple enough for icc to optimize away. My real code has state inside S and X object. For a long time, it was OK, then I added this "make_S" that should be completely optimized away, but icc becomes lost at this point.

Comment: @Jarod42 I compiled my real program with gcc 7.2. and with deleted move/copy ctors. gcc accepts the code. So if gcc is standard compliant, it means that C++17 garanteed copy elision applies in my case.

Answer (score 1):

## The `optional` way

If you have `C++17` the best option that ensures no copying is taking place and that the object is created inside the function is `std::optional` (or `boost:optional`). Thanks @Barry, you made my perfect little class obsolete :)

```
struct X
{
    X(int, int);
    X(const X&) = delete;
    X(X&&) = delete;
};

auto foo_no_copy(std::optional<X>& xo)
{
    X& x = xo.emplace(11, 24);
    // use x
}

auto test()
{
    std::optional<X> xo;
    foo_no_copy(xo);
    // use *xo
}
```

## Just a reference

Sometimes the simplest solution is the correct solution.

Depending on your scenario the other solutions might be overkill. If you can construct your object outside the function without any performance penalty then all you have to do is pass a reference:

```
auto foo(X& x) -> void;

auto test()
{
    X x{};

    foo(x);

    // use x
}
```

## Custom `Copy_elision` wrapper

Here is my original answer in case you don't have access to an `optional` class:

If you really must ensure the copy elision mechanism you can simulate on high level what the compiler would do on a low level: allocate memory on the caller and pass a pointer to it to the called function. Then the called function will use that memory to construct an object in place with placement new.

I have created a type safe RAII wrapper class for this:

```
template <class X>
struct Copy_elision
{
    std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(X)> storage_{};
    X* x_ = nullptr;

public:
    Copy_elision() = default;

    Copy_elision(const Copy_elision&) = delete;
    Copy_elision(Copy_elision&) = delete;
    auto operator=(const Copy_elision&) -> Copy_elision& = delete;
    auto operator=(Copy_elision&&) -> Copy_elision& = delete;

    ~Copy_elision()
    {
        if (x_)
            x_->~X();
    }

    template <class... Args>
    auto construct(Args&&... args) -> X&
    {
        x_ = new (&storage_) X{std::forward<Args>(args)...};

        return *x_;
    }

    auto get() const -> X* { return x_; }
};
```

Here is how to use it:

```
auto foo_no_copy(Copy_elision<X>& xce) -> X&
{
    X& x = xce.construct(11, 24);
    // work with x
    return x;
}

auto test()
{
    Copy_elision<X> x_storage;
    X& x = foo_no_copy(x_storage);
    // work with x
}
```

## Manual way (not recommenced)

If you are curious, here is the `Copy_elision` version without the wrapper class. I highly recommend against use of this version because it is very fragile:

- type safety loss
- no RAII: an exception will cause the destructor to not be called.

```
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>

struct X
{
    X(int, int);
    X(const X&) = delete; // can't copy
    X(X&&) = delete;      // can't move
};

auto foo_no_copy(void* xp/* , other params*/) -> X&
{
    X& x = *(new (xp) X{12, 24});
    // work with x
    return x;
}

auto test()
{
    std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(X)> x_storage;
    X& x = foo_no_copy(&x_storage);
    // work with x

    x.~X();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Assuming I have a no-op default constructor, why would it be better than creating a default constructed object and passing it by non-const reference to the function ?

Comment: @Bérenger I gave the most generic answer. I don't know what classes you have, so I assumed the worst: you can't have any kind of copy and you cant construct the object outside of the function. And so I did what the compiler would do for copy elision

Comment: Or like... `std::optional<X>`?

Comment: @Barry and... my world jut crumbled ... yes, `std::optional` is definitely better than a home made class.

Comment: @Barry I don't understand how optional helps here. The move constructor for `optional` simply calls the move constructor of the contained value, and it leaves the moved-from `optional` in the non-empty state, with its value in the moved-from state.

Comment: @NirFriedman `Copy_elision<X>` is basically `optional<X>`, without copy/move. So you can do the same thing - `auto foo_no_copy(optional<X>& xce) -> X& { X& x = xce.emplace(11, 24); ... }`

Comment: @Barry Ah, I see, ok. This works but IMHO is sub-optimal, still quite dangerous. A better solution is an altered optional that leaves behind an actual empty state, then you can just memcpy to move construct. It's theoretically UB but it will work and is safer than `foo_no_copy`.

Comment: @NirFriedman I don't understand you points, but "It's theoretically UB but it will work" scares me.

Comment: Guys, thank you for the detailed answer, but it does not answer my problem (maybe its my fault for not stating it more clearly). For me, if I can pass my final object location there is no more problem. But the problem is that I don't want to do that because it is ugly. I want my object to be *returned* by my function.

Comment: @Bérenger Get a better compiler? Even if icc doesn't correctly "guarantee" RVO, allowing it to return immovable objects, it should still kick in RVO and should not generate move assignment. That's just poor assembly... icc is good at specific things, but it's a horrible compiler at optimizing away abstractions. Horrible.

Comment: @NirFriedman Thanks for this comment, I was looking for this kind of feedback. It confirms what I experienced. Do you have documentation about icc failing to optimize these kind of abstractions? Regarding getting  a better compiler, the problem is that if I move to, say, gcc, I will loose some other optimizations that icc is good at. So am I doomed to write things all by hand because my compiler is dumb and there is no way to get both abstraction and performance? Aaargh, this is depressing :(

Comment: @Bérenger there is no perfect tool. What you do is compare the benefits and advantages of the tools available to you, make a choice and you assume it. Or write a better tool, but that also comes with assuming your choice.

Comment: @bolov It is still depressing. I am not asking for the moon. The compiler has the code of the function, it even inlines it. Why on earth would it not elide the copy? There is no clever trick, there is literally nothing to do once the function is inlined...

Comment: @Bérenger I don't think this is the kind of thing that is documented, even for open source compilers, let alone a closed source one. My personal view is that icc's conformance to the standard and build times are so bad, that it has to really outperform gcc to be worthwhile. All this time you've spent on SO, is time that if you were using gcc, you could spend on other optimizations. And, IME, I am skeptical that icc really outperforms gcc at all, let alone by much, on a real program. YMMV.

Comment: @NirFriedman Thanks for the valuable piece of information. I was not thinking about official icc documents, but rather people experiences about how icc "feels" compared to say gcc regarding e.g. refactoring a piece of code into modular components by gradually building up zero-cost (or in theory zero-cost) abstractions. I wasn't able to find anything detailed.